# Using chop and explode to extract string from file path but result array doesn't print the letter "n"

Tags: php, arrays, string, explode

I'm using `explode()` to extract a string (`$style`) from font filenames in a particular directory, then printing some styles based on the resulting array. The results get truncated if the string contains the letter **n**.

Server is Ubuntu Bionic running **PHP7.3**. After the `if (in_array())` statement failed to catch the string I added a `print_r()` statement to debug. That's when I saw that the letter `n` was acting as a boundary and truncating the output.

Font names all take the format `$family`-`$style`-webfont.woff (or .woff2), e.g., `merriweather-bold-webfont.woff`.

**Sample code:**

```
function my_fontload() {
    // Locate font files
    $font_path = get_stylesheet_directory_uri() . "/path/to/fonts/";
    $files = glob(get_stylesheet_directory( __FILE__ ) . '/path/to/fonts/*.woff', GLOB_BRACE);

    $suffix = '-webfont';
      foreach($files as &$file) {

        $font = basename($file, ".woff");
        $font = chop($font,$suffix);

        $family = explode("-", $font);
        $family = $family[0];

        $style = explode("-", $font);


        echo '@font-face{font-family:\''.$family.'\';src:url('. esc_url(( $font_path).basename($file)).'2)format(\'woff2\'),url('.esc_url(( $font_path).basename($file)).')format(\'woff\');';
        if (in_array('thin', $style) || in_array( 'hairline', $style)) {
            // Do stuff
        } elseif (in_array('regular', $style) || in_array( 'normal', $style)) {
           // Do other stuff
        } else {
            // Do default stuff
        }
        // Other logic here

        // debugging
        print_r($style);
    }

    unset ($file);
}
```

**Expected result:**

```
(
    [0] => merriweather
    [1] => regular
)

(
    [0] => merriweather
    [1] => thin
)

(
    [0] => merriweather
    [1] => hairline
)
```

**Actual result:**

```
(
    [0] => merriweather
    [1] => regular
)

(
    [0] => merriweather
    [1] => thi
)

(
    [0] => merriweather
    [1] => hairli
)
```

It's as if **n** is being treated as some literal, like a newline character or something. What's going on?

Comment: Why using explode twice? Should it be `list($family, $style) = explode('-', $font);`? Notice in your current code you set both family and style to the style var...

Comment: Still learning PHP. Didn't know about `list()`. I'll give that a shot.

Comment: The issue is your chop function - try replacing it with: `$font = str_replace($suffix, '', $font);`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First of all I recommend change the syntax to:

```
list($family, $style) = explode('-', $font, 2);
```

As it seem you only want to compare only the style. Then you don't need the `in_array` but you can just use `if` statement.

To your trim issue: as you can see in the [chop documentation](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.chop.php), the second argument said which **letters** to remove from the right side of the string - you specific the letters: `-,w,e,b,f,o,n,t` so starting fron the rightest letter - if it one of those it trimed - when encounter first letter who no it stop ->

Therefor you get `thi` instead of `thin` as remove `n` but not `i`. And `hairli` instead of `hairline` and both `n` and `e` are in the letters `-,w,e,b,f,o,n,t` but not `i`.

Live example: [3v4l](https://3v4l.org/uHdZA).

If all you want (and I guess this what you want) is to remove the suffix use:

```
substr($fonf, 0, - strlen('-webfont'));
```

**Edited:**

This is example for your code:

```
$files = ['merriweather-regular-webfont.woff','merriweather-thin-webfont.woff','merriweather-hairline-webfont.woff'];
foreach($files as $file) {
    $font = basename($file, ".woff"); // remove the file type
    $font = str_replace('-webfont', '', $font); // remove the suffix
    list($family, $style) = explode('-', $font, 2); // explode for 2 parts: family and style
    echo "Family: $family and style: $style" . PHP_EOL; 
    if (in_array($style, ['thin', 'hairline'])) {
        echo esc_html('font-weight:100;font-style:normal;'); 
    } elseif (in_array($style, ['regular', 'normal'])) {
       echo esc_html('font-weight:400;font-style:normal;');
    } else {
        echo esc_html('font-weight:400;font-style:normal;'); // Fallback 
    }
}
```

Comment: I take it you mean `substr($font, 0, - strlen('-webfont'));`?

Comment: @Chris Yes. You can use it instead the `chop` function. After that continue with the `explode` and the `if` checks

Comment: That worked. But when I replaced the `explode()` bits like this: `foreach($files as &$file) {

        $font = basename($file, ".woff");
        substr($font, 0, - strlen('-webfont'));

        //$family = explode("-", $font);
        //$family = $family[0];

        //$style = explode("-", $font);
        list($family, $style) = explode('-', $font);` etc., it does not work.

Comment: @Chris you missing assign to `$font` - updated my answer with your code

Comment: Ah, I see — missing the "2". Tried the updated code but it still doesn't work. If I'm understanding how `list()` works it _should_. FWIW `$font = str_replace($suffix, '', $font);` also works to trim the suffix and makes it easier for me to understand the code.

Comment: Does the family and style echo fine? what does not works? Please do `$a = explode("-", $font); and then print `$a` and share what inside. the 2 is just for make sure it will explode for MAX 2 parts

Comment: Simplified output:

`(
    [0] => merriweather
    [1] => hairline
)
@font-face{font-family:'merriweather';src:url(https://dev.dev/path/to/font/foo-hairline-webfont.woff2)format('woff2'),url(https://dev.dev/path/to/font/merriweather-hairline-webfont.woff)format('woff');font-weight:400;}Array
`

The font-weight should be 100 if this worked. If I revert to the old code it outputs the correct weight.

Comment: I am sorry but I don't understand whats wrong (I have no idea what is the `font-weight`) Maybe it is in the `// Do stuff` part of your code in the question?  hows you `if` statement works? I will updated my answer again

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/193659/discussion-between-chris-and-dwinder).